# "Simple" condition that would prove a function transcendental

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, limits-and-convergence

I've already asked the question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703824/simple-condition-that-would-prove-a-function-transcendental) but there are still no answers, so I'm going to ask it here.

I conjectured that for every algebraic function $f(x)$ that is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, its $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is either $\infty$, $-\infty$, or a finite value, so:

> If $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ and its $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is not $\infty$, $-\infty$, nor a finite value, then $f(x)$ is transcendental.

If this is true, how could it be proved?

Comment: "It would amount to showing that no algebraic function is periodic" - Why?

Comment: @Qfwfq That shouldn't be there.

Comment: I guess "approach anything" means anything in $[-\infty,+\infty]$.  So "does not approach anything" means $\liminf f(x) < \limsup f(x)$.  A version of the question would then be: can a nontrivial algebraic function have infinitely many zeros?

Comment: Do you mean algebraic as graph of an algebraic curve, or the solution of ODE with polynomial coefficients? If first, then your statement is clearly correct, and if the second, then $sin(x)$ satisfies $f'' = -f$.

Comment: The following is marginally related (deals primarily with explicit algebraic functions): Fred Richman, [*Algebraic functions, calculus style*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00927872.2011.584337), **Communications in Algebra** 40 #7 (2012), pp. 2671-2683 ([27 July 2010 preprint version](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.304.6160&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Comment: @Lev I mean algebraic in the sense of algebraic curves, not in the sense of ODEs.

Comment: A limit, if it exists, is a single number. It cannot approach anything.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks for pointing that out. I will correct the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Your conjecture is true. Indeed, suppose that a function $f\colon\R\to\R$ is continuous and algebraic, so that
$$\sum_{j\in[n]_0}p_j(x)f(x)^j=0\tag{1}$$
for all $x\in\R$, where $[n]_0:=\{0,\dots,n\}$, $n$ is a natural number, and, for each $j\in[n]_0$, $p_j$ is a polynomial function of some degree $m_j$, so that for some real $a_j\ne0$
$$p_j(x)=(a_j+o(1))x^{m_j}\tag{2}$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Suppose now that for some real $c$ and some sequence $(x_m)$ in $\R$ converging to $\infty$ we have $f(x_m)\to c$. Then, by (1) and (2),
$$p(c):=\sum_{j\in J}a_j c^j=0,\tag{3}$$
where $J$ is the (nonempty) set of all $j\in[n]_0$ such that for all $i\in[n]_0$ we have $m_j\ge m_i$. So, $c$ must be in the finite set of the roots of the polynomial $p$.

On the other hand, if your conjecture were false, then, by the intermediate value theorem, there would be infinitely (even uncountably) many real $c$ such that for some sequence $(x_m)$ in $\R$ converging to $\infty$ we have $f(x_m)\to c$.

So, your conjecture is true.